# Why stack trace shows 3 calls on one line inside .ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following line of code inside `main.ts`:

```
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And in call stack it's shown as 3 calls like this:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Apparently the underlying js has three low-level function calls that check for something, etc. On the other hand, devtools could be better at collapsing the callstack for source-mapped code. Report it on https://crbug.com if it's not reported already,

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks, it's [indeed so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40491193/2545680). I just expected devtools to workaround this. I'll consider reporting the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, indeed, here is the JS code

```
(function (System, SystemJS) {
    (function (require, exports, module, __filename, __dirname, global, GLOBAL) {
        "use strict";
        var platform_browser_dynamic_1 = require("@angular/platform-browser-dynamic");
        var app_module_1 = require("./app.module");
        var platform = platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic();
        platform.bootstrapModule(app_module_1.AppModule);
        //# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
    }).apply(__cjsWrapper.exports, __cjsWrapper.args);
})(System, System);
```

that is mapped to

```
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and indeed there are 3 function calls before `bootstrapModule` is called:

`outer IIFE`, `inner IIFE`, and `platform.bootstrapModule(app_module_1.AppModule);`.

Answer (score 2):

chrome doesn't run typescript, it runs javascript.
In order to run typescript there are tools that convert it to javascript (either as part of build or in runtime in your browser).
Those tools also create a source map to map the typescript lines to javascript lines so you can see the original code that caused an issue instead of seeing the new auto generated javascript.
So your 1 line in typescript was in fact multiple lines in the generated javascript.

if you see in their repo, you can see they explain it as well:
**TypeScript compiles to readable, standards-based JavaScript**

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript